# Support Multiple Value Selection not working in dependent LOV in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, multi-select, lov

I have created View Criteria for **EmployeesVO**. For **ManagerId** and **DepartmentId** I defined Support Multiple Value Selection. Issue is following - after choosing multiple values in **ManagerId** I expect to have refreshed list of values for **DepartmentId** field. Unfortunately **DepartmentId** is refreshed only for first value in **ManagerId** field, not for all choosen **ManagerId's**.

Here is what I have, I can choose only **DepartmentId** = 60:
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbqEF.jpg)

And here is what I want to see, refreshed list with all **DepartmentId's** related to chosen **ManagerId's**  :
[Requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIrL9.jpg)

Comment: make sure you follow all steps correctly: 
 https://quickadf.blogspot.com/2015/06/multi-level-dependent-lov-list-of-values.html  http://waslleysouza.com.br/en/2014/10/defining-cascading-list-values-adf/     https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-create-multi-level-cascading-dependent-list-of-values-using-bc4j

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not solve the problem, because I want to have multiple-choice LOV, not single-choice LOV.